# ascx control visible false displaying issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, treeview

My user control is displaying only the first ascx but when I'm navigating to other ascx the content is not displaying what am I doing wrong??!

The idea is On my aspx page I have on the left hand side TreeView for each of every node in the TreeView I want to load a different ascx which going to change only the right hand side of the page.

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/InternalReports.Master" CodeBehind="Reports.aspx.vb" Inherits="DispatchSoftware.Reports" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefix" TagName="rptReports" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptReport.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefixTmeOfDay" TagName="rptTimeOfDay" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptTimeOfDay.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefixTrending" TagName="rptTrending" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptTrending.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefixTopSevenIncidents" TagName="rptTopSevenIncidents" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptTopSevenIncidents.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefixTimeCategoriesComparison" TagName="rptTimeCategoriesComparison" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptTimeCategoriesComparison.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefixIncidentPerCategory" TagName="rptIncidentPerCategory" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptIncidentPerCategory.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefixMaps" TagName="rptMaps" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptMaps.ascx" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftContent" runat="server">

 <div id="leftCol">
        <div class="elementHeader">
            <span class="text">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFilter" runat="server" Text="Filter"></asp:Label>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="filterWrapperDiv" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
             <telerik:RadPanelBar runat="server" ID="rpbMainMenu" Width="248px" Height="517px" ExpandMode="FullExpandedItem">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadPanelItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Layout/Reports.png" Expanded="true" Text="Reports">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div style="border: 0px solid red; height: 400px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; overflow: auto;">
                            <telerik:RadTreeView runat="Server" ID="rtvReports" EnableDragAndDrop="false" Height="300px">
                                <Nodes>
                                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Statistical Report" Value="StatisticalReport" Expanded="true" CssClass="GeneralFontShape">
                                        <Nodes>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Time of Day" Value="TimeofDay" >
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Trending" Value="Trending">
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Top 7 Incidents" Value="Top7Incidents">
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Incidents Per Category" Value="IncidentsPerCategory">
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                        </Nodes>
                                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Incident Comparisons" Value="IncidentComparisons" Expanded="true" CssClass="GeneralFontShape">
                                        <Nodes>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Incident Loss" Value="IncidentLoss">
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                        </Nodes>
                                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Geographic Locations" Value="GeographicLocations" Expanded="true" CssClass="GeneralFontShape">
                                        <Nodes>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Maps" Value="Maps">
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                        </Nodes>
                                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                </Nodes>
                            </telerik:RadTreeView>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </telerik:RadPanelItem>
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadPanelBar>
        </div>
        <div class="elementFooter"></div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>

<%--Right Handside--%>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightContent" runat="server">        
    <ReportsPrefix:rptReports ID="ucReports" runat="server" Visible="True" />
    <ReportsPrefixTmeOfDay:rptTimeOfDay ID="ucTimeOfDay" runat="server" Visible="False" /> 
    <ReportsPrefixTrending:rptTrending ID="ucTrending" runat="server" Visible="False" /> 
    <ReportsPrefixTopSevenIncidents:rptTopSevenIncidents ID="ucTopSevenIncidents" runat="server" Visible="False" /> 
    <ReportsPrefixTimeCategoriesComparison:rptTimeCategoriesComparison ID="ucTimeCategoriesComparison" runat="server" Visible="False" />
    <ReportsPrefixIncidentPerCategory:rptIncidentPerCategory ID="ucIncidentPerCategory" runat="server" Visible="False" />
    <ReportsPrefixMaps:rptMaps ID="ucMaps" runat="server" Visible="False" />  
</asp:Content>
```

VB Code:

```
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Reports
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private m_User As UserInfo = Nothing
    Private m_SessionID As String
    Private m_qrptTOD As String
    Private m_qrptTRN As String
    Private m_qrptTOS As String
    Private m_qrptIPC As String
    Private m_qrptCIL As String
    Private m_qrptGEO As String

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        m_User = New UserInfo()

        If m_User.UserID = 0 Then
            Response.Redirect(Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/QuickLogOut.aspx?SessionID=" + m_User.SessionID + "&qCC=" & m_User.CompanyCode))
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            GenerateDataSets()
            GenerateLabels()
            GenerateLinks()
            GenerateControls()
            GenerateOther()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()
        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("SessionID")) Then
                m_SessionID = Request.QueryString("SessionID")
                m_qrptTOD = Request.QueryString("qrptTOD")
                m_qrptTRN = Request.QueryString("qrptTRN")
                m_qrptTOS = Request.QueryString("qrptTOS")
                m_qrptIPC = Request.QueryString("qrptIPC")
                m_qrptCIL = Request.QueryString("qrptCIL")
                m_qrptGEO = Request.QueryString("qrptGEO")
            ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("SessionID")) Then
                m_SessionID = Session("SessionID")
            End If

            If m_qrptTOD = "tod" Then
                '=== Clearing the right hand side and loading the new ascx.
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Clear()

                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptTimeOfDay.ascx")))

            End If
            If m_qrptTRN = "trn" Then
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Clear()
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptTrending.ascx")))
            End If

            If m_qrptTOS = "tos" Then
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Clear()
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptTopSevenIncidents.ascx")))
            End If

            If m_qrptIPC = "ipc" Then
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Clear()
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptIncidentPerCategory.ascx")))
            End If

            If m_qrptCIL = "cil" Then
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Clear()
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptTimeCategoriesComparison.ascx")))
            End If

            If m_qrptGEO = "geo" Then
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Clear()
                Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptMaps.ascx")))
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GenerateDataSets()
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GenerateLabels()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GenerateLinks()
        Dim subTreeStatisticalReport As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("StatisticalReport")
        Dim subTreeIncidentComparisons As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentComparisons")
        Dim subTreeGeographicLocations As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("GeographicLocations")

        Dim statTimeOfDayNode As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("TimeofDay")
        Dim statTrendsNode As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Trending")
        Dim statTopSevenIncidents As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Top7Incidents")
        Dim statIncidentPerCategory As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentsPerCategory")
        Dim compIncidentLoss As RadTreeNode = subTreeIncidentComparisons.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentLoss")
        Dim GeoMaps As RadTreeNode = subTreeGeographicLocations.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Maps")


        statTimeOfDayNode.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptTOD=tod")
        statTrendsNode.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptTRN=trn")
        statTopSevenIncidents.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptTOS=tos")
        statIncidentPerCategory.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptIPC=ipc")
        compIncidentLoss.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptCIL=cil")
        GeoMaps.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptGEO=geo")

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GenerateControls()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GenerateOther()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you debugged this?  I can see several holes where your code may do nothing at all.  Put some breakpoints in and see if it's even trying to load your control(s).

Comment: When I'm doing inspect element on the right hand side It the content is like empty. It's working on my local machine but not on the production server.

Comment: Probably a path issue then. Maybe when your loading controls from server side use paths that start with **~/** if that doesn't work try [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get a physical location to the file your loading. Also you may want to re-throw the error's i your try/catch so you can see what is happening. Right now your suppressing the errors completely.

Comment: I changed my code on the server side using :Page.ResolveUrl now it's complaining on the client side <%@ Register TagPrefix="ReportsPrefix" TagName="rptReports" Src="~/Controls/Reports/rptReport.ascx" %> saying that it doesn't exist. the thing is on my local machine it's working fine but when I'm compiling it and putting it on the production it's causing issues.